# Max group value in Webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a report in Webi 4.0 with Store name and sales revenue per store. I have created a text box and I want to display the Store name with the highest sales revenue. I can get the max value to appear with:

```
=Max([Sales revenue]) IN ([Store name])
```

This successfully shows me the highest sales revenue but what I want is the actual store name that corresponds to that value?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the definition of Max Sales to:

=Max([Sales revenue]) ForAll ([Store name])

Then youe Max Sales Store Name variable can be defined as:

=If([Sales revenue]=[Max Sales];[Store name])

regards

James